# How can I create multiple drag and drop file uploads, with progress bar using php & javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, file, drag

I want to be able to create a drag and drop solution for dropping multiple files at once, screening out invalid mime types, with a progress bar on each, using javascript, php, and html.  Can Anyone Help?

Comment: HTML5 should be a good solution for you

Answer (score 1):

I found this great script set on a blog post, it has a demo and a download link.

http://www.amitpatil.me/drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar/

The original script only handles one file at a time and only .jpg files.

I personally modified it to pass the mimeType so that it could store multiple mimeTypes, not just jpg.  It also does multiple files at once. Also it has a list of allowed mime types so all others are blocked.  The php file stores the appropriate extension.  You can easily modify this so that it suites your allowed mimeType needs.

For my purposes I set the upload max size to 200 megs because I want people to be able to upload videos.  You can set your own max size.

Here are my replacement scripts, it works great.

Anywhere in your html script add these lines where you want the drop box to be.

```
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/uploadstyle.css">
            <div id="dropbox">
              <div class="text">
                Drop Files Here
              </div>
            </div>
            <script src="js/filereader.js"></script>
            <script src="js/upload.js"></script>
```

upload.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dropbox;
  var oprand = {
    dragClass : "active",
    on: {
      load: function(e, file) {
        var imageTypes = ["image/bmp", "image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "text/plain", "application/pdf", "video/mpeg", "video/x-mpeg", "video/quicktime", "video/mpeg-4","video/mp4"];
        var arrayLength = imageTypes.length;
        var match = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
          if(file.type == imageTypes[i]) match = imageTypes[i];
        }

        // check file type
        //var imageType = /image.*/;
        //if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
        if (!match) {
          alert("File \""+file.name+"\" is not a valid mime type for this upload [" + file.type + "]");
          return false;
        }

        // check file size
        if (parseInt(file.size / 1024) > 200050) {
          alert("File \""+file.name+"\" is too big.Max allowed size is 2 MB.");
          return false;
        }

        create_box(e,file,match);
      },
    }
  };

  FileReaderJS.setupDrop(document.getElementById('dropbox'), oprand);

});

create_box = function(e,file,mimeType){
  var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*100000)+3);
  var imgName = file.name; // not used, Irand just in case if user wanrand to print it.
  var src       = e.target.result;
  if (mimeType=='text/plain' || mimeType=='application/pdf' || mimeType=='video/mpeg' || mimeType=='video/x-mpeg' ||
    mimeType=='video/mpeg-4' || mimeType=='video/mp4' || mimeType=='video/quicktime')
  {
    src = '/images/' + 'missing-mcsanl.gov_.png'
  }

  var template = '<div class="eachImage" id="'+rand+'">';
  template += '<span class="preview" id="'+rand+'"><img src="'+src+'"><span class="overlay"><span class="updone"></span></span>';
  template += '</span>';
  template += '<div class="progress" id="'+rand+'"><span></span></div>';

  if($("#dropbox .eachImage").html() == null)
    $("#dropbox").html(template);
  else
    $("#dropbox").append(template);

  // upload image
  upload(file,rand,mimeType);
}

upload = function(file,rand,mimeType){
  // now upload the file
  var xhr = new Array();
  xhr[rand] = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr[rand].open("post", "ajax_fileupload.php?mimeType="+encodeURIComponent(mimeType), true);

  xhr[rand].upload.addEventListener("progress", function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
      $(".progress[id='"+rand+"'] span").css("width",(event.loaded / event.total) * 100 + "%");
      $(".preview[id='"+rand+"'] .updone").html(((event.loaded / event.total) * 100).toFixed(2)+"%");
    }
    else {
      alert("Failed to compute file upload length");
    }
  }, false);

  xhr[rand].onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
    if (xhr[rand].readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr[rand].status === 200) {
        $(".progress[id='"+rand+"'] span").css("width","100%");
        $(".preview[id='"+rand+"']").find(".updone").html("100%");
        $(".preview[id='"+rand+"'] .overlay").css("display","none");
      } else {
        alert("Error : Unexpected error while uploading file");
      }
    }
  };

  // Set headers
  xhr[rand].setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
  xhr[rand].setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.fileName);
  xhr[rand].setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.fileSize);
  xhr[rand].setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);

  // Send the file (doh)
  xhr[rand].send(file);
}
```

ajax_fileupload.php

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('php://input');
switch ($_REQUEST['mimeType']) {
  //see if we can do something about text dropped into a window to be used for youtube/vimeo links
  //case 'video/youtube':
  //case 'video/vimeo':
  case 'image/bmp':
    echo $filename = md5(time().uniqid()).".bmp";
    $returnVal=true;
    break;
  case 'image/gif':
    echo $filename = md5(time().uniqid()).".gif";
    $returnVal=true;
    break;
  case 'image/jpeg':
    echo $filename = md5(time().uniqid()).".jpg";
    $returnVal=true;
    break;
  case 'image/png':
    echo $filename = md5(time().uniqid()).".png";
    $returnVal=true;
    break;
  //case 'url/external':
  case 'text/plain':
    echo $filename = md5(time().uniqid()).".txt";
    $returnVal=true;
    break;
  case 'application/pdf':
    echo $filename = md5(time().uniqid()).".pdf";
    $returnVal=true;
    break;
  case 'video/mpeg':
    echo $filename = md5(time().uniqid()).".mpg";
    $returnVal=true;
    break;
  case 'video/x-mpeg':
    echo $filename = md5(time().uniqid()).".xmpeg";
    $returnVal=true;
    break;
  //case 'video/x-flv':
  case 'video/quicktime':
    echo $filename = md5(time().uniqid()).".mov";
    $returnVal=true;
    break;
  case 'video/mpeg-4':
    echo $filename = md5(time().uniqid()).".mp4";
    $returnVal=true;
    break;
  case 'video/mp4':
    echo $filename = md5(time().uniqid()).".mp4";
    $returnVal=true;
    break;
    break;
  default:
    $returnVal=false;
    break;
}

file_put_contents("uploads/".$filename,$str);
// In demo version i delete uplaoded file immideately, Please remove it later
//unlink("uploads/".$filename);
//file_put_contents("uploads/files.txt",var_export($_REQUEST,true));
?>
```

You will need to visit the link and download that content first, and then apply the replacements.  I did not provide everything here.